# Как можно найти самое длинное слово в списке без встроенных функций на python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Есть список, внутри которого, соответственно, есть слова. Необходимо найти и вывести самое длинное слово, но **без использования встроенных функций** типа `len, min, max` и т.д. Как можно такое провернуть?

**upd:** Слова вводятся пользователем. Т.е заранее невозможно узнать кол-во слов в списке.

Comment: Считать вручную по буквам.

Comment: Прям вот вообще никаких встроенных функций нельзя использовать? Или мб есть точный перечень? И как вводятся слова, в одну строку? Или по-отдельности, тогда какое условие окончания ввода?

Answer (score 1):

Наибольший элемент в массиве.

```
def countSymbols(s):
    t=0
    for i in s:
        t+=1
    return t

items = ["111","1111111","22222"]

maxStr=""

for elem in items:
    if countSymbols(elem)>countSymbols(maxStr):
        maxStr=elem

print(maxStr)
```

Comment: Не используйте имена встроенных функций в качестве имен переменных

Comment: @insolor это демонстрационный пример.

Comment: Тем более. Если вы используете плохие практике где-то локально у себя в коде, который никто не увидит - это одно дело. Совсем другое дело, когда вы показываете пример, на который будут смотреть тысячи новичков, которые не поймут, где хорошие практики, где плохие.

Comment: Если длину самого длинного слова хранить отдельно, то время выполнения сократится примерно в два раза (в среднем, в зависимости от входных данных).

Answer (score 0):

```py
# функция возвращает длину слова
def wordLen(word):
    length = 0
    for letter in word:
        length += 1
    return length

# если слова вводятся в строчку
# words = input().split()

# если слова вводятся каждое на новой строке
# words = list()
# word = input()
# while word != '':
    # words.append(word.strip())
    # word = input()

# по умолчанию самое длинное слово - первое
longest_word = words[0]
for word in words:
    if wordLen(word) > wordLen(longest_word):
        longest_word = word

print(longest_word)
```

Comment: См. комментарий к другому ответу про время выполнения.